# Extract function names from function calls in C files

Tags: ruby, regex

Is it posible to extract function calls in C source files, e.g.,

```
...
myfunc(1);
...
```

or

```
...
myfunc(anotherfunc(1, 2));
....
```

by just using Ruby regular expression? If not, would a parser generator such as ANTLR be useful?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full-proof pattern for finding out method calls but should just serve the pattern that you are interested in.

```
[a-zA-Z\s]*\([a-zA-Z0-9]*(\([a-zA-Z0-9\s]*[\s,]*[\sa-zA-Z0-9]*\))?\);
```

This regex will match following method call patterns.

```
1. myfunc(another(one,two));
2. myfunc();
3. myfunc(another());
4. myfunc(oneArg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the regular expressions already written from grammar that are used by emacs -- imenu , etags, ecb, c-mode etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the purest sense you can't, because the possibility to nest function calls recursively makes it a non-regular language. That is, you cannot write a regular expression that matches an arbitrary function call and extracts all of the contained function names.

But of course you could search incrementally for sequences of characters allowed in function names (ie., must start with a letter or underscore, followed by letters, underscore, numbers, etc...) followed by an left parenthesis, or something along those lines.

Keep in mind, however, that any such approach is prone to errors: what if a function is referenced in a comment? What if it appears inside a string constant? Really, to catch all the special cases you would have to (almost) properly parse the full C file.

Most modern regular expression engines have features to parse more than regular languages e.g. by means of back-references to subexpressions. But you shouldn't go down that road. With a proper parser such as ANTLR that can parse context-free languages you'll make your own life a lot easier.